# Print PDF headless chrome in a java program

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, headless

how to print pdf in selenium headless chrome driver in a java program? There are few examples by using "--print-to-pdf" option. 
But this isn't working in a java program, could someone help me in this?

Thanks in advance!
~Balakumar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate PDF with selenium chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729046/generate-pdf-with-selenium-chrome-driver)